# "unsupported get request" when trying to access test user with Facebook Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have a couple test users that I have created and I'm trying to test my "check for mutual friends" functionality.

So I have 3 test users, and 2 of them have the other one as a mutual friend.

However, when I try to pass the URL of

```
/<id>/friends
```

to the FBSDKGraphRequest call, I am getting the following error:

```
Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

I have logged into the app through the iOS simulator with all 3 of the accounts, and I can pull back the friends list for all 3 users with the normal "me/friends" URL passed into the FBSDKGraphRequest call.

I have also tried passing in explicit ID's to that same request with real users (my own and my wife's) and that works fine.  However when I try to do it with test users it is giving me this problem.

Anyone have any clue what is going on?

EDIT:

Also when in the graph application on Facebook's website, I get the same errors when trying to pull back the endpoint for the test users that have the app installed, but when I do it for real users who have the app installed it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the reason why this was happening and I figured I'd post an answer in case someone else runs into the issue.

It all boils down to you not being able to mix/match between *real* accounts and *test* accounts.  When I logged in as a test user, I could then pull back the friend lists for the test users, and if I tried to pull back a real users friends list, I would receive that error.

So it all basically boiled down to me not understanding that you cannot go between test and real Facebook accounts.